# Button click event callback not being called -- jest/enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test that tests calling of a callback method on button click with the argument passed as the value of text input of my Estimate component.

Test:

```
let obj
let fn
describe('Estimate tests', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    fn = jest.fn()
    obj = mount(<Estimate onPress={fn} />)
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    obj.unmount()
  })

  test('Button click returns text input value', () => {
    obj.find('TextInput').first().simulate('change', { target: { value: 61606 } })
    obj.find('Button').first().simulate('click')
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(61606)
  })
})
```

Estimate.jsx:

```
export class Estimate extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    const { onPress } = this.props

    // @todo remove the excess margin and spacing above this component
    return (
      <Form
        name="estimateForm"
        ref={(ref) => {
          this.estimateForm = ref
        }}
      >
        <Actions style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Button
            type="text"
            style={{ marginBottom: -em(0.5) }}
            onPress={() => onPress(this.estimateForm.values)}
            title={t('estimateShippingAndTax')}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder={t('postalCode')}
            name="estimate"
            style={{ width: 100 }}
            validate="postalCode"
          />
        </Actions>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  [61606]
But it was not called.

  31 |     obj.find('TextInput').first().simulate('change', { target: { value: 61606 } })
  32 |     obj.find('Button').first().simulate('click')
> 33 |     expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(61606)
     |                ^
  34 |   })
  35 | })
  36 |
```

What's going on? onPress is associated with the buttons on press. Yet it's not even being called.

Comment: Maybe `TextInput` shouldn't be in `Actions`? Also, there is no `onChange` handler in `TextIntput`...

Comment: Is there an alternative way to change or input text to that textinput?

Answer (score 0):

Since you operates on [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) simulating change(that is the same as calling `target.props.onChange(...)`) will not work.

For web-oriented app it could be done with mutating `.value` instead of `simulate('change', ...)` but since it's React Native its TextInput in [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value) it should be supplied with explicit onChange/onChangeText handler. Then you would be able to use `simulate('change')` as you do.

The last thing I want to highlight: for controlled component it will be neccessary to call [`.update()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) on enzyme's wrapper like that:

```
test('Button click returns text input value', () => {
    obj.find('TextInput').first().simulate('change', { target: { value: 61606 } });
    obj.update();
    obj.find('Button').first().simulate('click');
    expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith([61606]); // also here you will retrieve array with values not single one
})
```

[UPD] actually TextInput's value [can be set up](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value) in uncontrolled way through `ref`(but I believe using it in controlled way is better):

```
obj.instance()._textInputRefYouShouldBound.setNativeProps({text: '61606'});
obj.find('Button').first().simulate('click')
expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['61606'])
```

Comment: _textInputRefYouShouldBound what is this? How do I get reference to this?

Comment: i created a method getRef inside the component and that gets reference to textinput and later do I use this to get TextInputs reference?

Comment: @Ackman sorry I don't understand what do you mean. Have you ever worked with `ref` in React code(not necessarily React Native)?

Comment: I am new to react and still in the process of going through documentation. can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: in answer I've added a link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value to pretty close case. Check what's going on in `ref=` prop and how that value is used. In long term I believe you better to refactor component to be controlled(first and second links in my answer for more information)

Comment: For the current case 'uncontrolled' obj.instance.setText().setNativeProps({ text: '61606' }) is this what I am supposed to do? set text value from outside?

Comment: `obj` is Enzyme wrapper around your `<Estimate>`, [`obj.instance()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html) - sorry, it's a method, my mistake - returns React Component itself. Then you need a `ref` you have created inside of your `<Estimate>`. Once `.setText()` returns ref to TextInput then your snippet is correct.